# Combine or construct korean letters

Tags: string, unicode, go

Is there anyway that I can combine this Korean consonants and vowels into a complete character.

For example if I have

```
  ㄱㅏㅁㅅㅏㅎㅏㅂㄴㅣㄷㅏ
```

It would be

```
  감사합니다
```

Is there any way to do this?
I can only think of bruteforcing every case that would have to count many many cases.

Below is my try. Not optimal and take too much time.

```
if strings.Contains(input_str, "ㅏㄴㅈ") {
    input_str = strings.Replace(input_str, "ㅇㅏㄴㅈ", "앉", -1)
}

if strings.Contains(input_str, "ㅏㄹㅂ") {
    input_str = strings.Replace(input_str, "ㅂㅏㄹㅂ", "밟", -1)
}

if strings.Contains(input_str, "ㅏㅂㅅ") {
    input_str = strings.Replace(input_str, "ㄱㅏㅂㅅ", "값", -1)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is Unicode normalization to compose hangul jamo.
Go supports this but not (yet) in the standard library. See [this related issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1621).

To import the external [`go.text/unicode/norm`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm) package use:

```
go get -u golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm
```

You probably want to use [NFC](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) which does a

- Canonical Decomposition,
- followed by Canonical Composition (which is what you want)

Example for NFD (decomposition):

```
// 앉 -> 앉
fmt.Println( string( norm.NFD.AppendString(nil, "앉") ) )
```

Example for NFC (composition):

```
// 앉 -> 앉
fmt.Println( string( norm.NFC.AppendString(nil, "앉") ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone recently did a write-up on unicode in Korean: http://www.programminginkorean.com/programming/hangul-in-unicode/composing-syllables-in-unicode/

Comment: I let the author know about it. It's still available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190512031142/http://www.programminginkorean.com/programming/hangul-in-unicode/composing-syllables-in-unicode/

Comment: Oh, it is SO nice when someone has kept the archived version of the site referred to. Nice work. It's a good site, as well.